# Fetch limited list of categories and limited list of related items

Tags: mysql, symfony, pdo, doctrine-orm

I'm developing an API for IOS app in Symfony2.
At this time there are 10 categories in db, and 40 coaches(this is an app related term) (every coach has a relationship with particular category, 1:n/n:1 relationship).
When user opens the app, he/she must see list of categories (limit 5) and right after the each category name list of 5 coaches (limit 5):
[image]

At this time I am fetching it like this, but it seems that LIMIT and OFFSET won't work properly with category list (problem is appearing when there is different qauntity of coaches, for example, if there are 3 coaches in cat1, 2 coaches in cat 2, and 5 coaches in cat3 and so on...):

```
// Temporary solution
$connection = $this->getEntityManager()
            ->getConnection()
            ->prepare('
              SELECT
              c.id AS category_id,
              c.name AS category_name,
              c.icon AS category_icon,
              co3.id AS coach_id,
              co3.name AS coach_name,
              co3.started_at AS coach_started_at
              FROM category AS c
              LEFT JOIN
              (
                SELECT co.* FROM coach AS co
                WHERE (
                  SELECT COUNT(*)
                  FROM coach AS co2
                  WHERE co.category_id = co2.category_id
                  AND co.id <= co2.id
                ) <= :coachLimit
              ) AS co3 ON c.id = co3.category_id
              LIMIT :categoryOffset, :categeoryLimit
            ');
    $connection->bindValue('coachLimit', 5);

    $connection->bindValue('categoryOffset', $offset);
    $connection->bindValue('categeoryLimit', $limit);
    $connection->execute();

    $results = $connection->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

My question is, how should I compose (or write) SQL to fetch list of categories and related coaches with LIMIT and OFFSET in category and only LIMIT in coaches?
What is the best way to retrieve records and related records by limit?

Comment: Sqlfiddles are always fun (although I think the site might be down right now)

Comment: @Strawberry Sure, it's not working..